# contingence two columns pandas python3

Tags: python, pandas

I'm looking for if there is a direct way to count the sum of the elements of `b` when `a=1`.

```
a

   a  b     c   d
0  4  2   NaN   7
1  1  2  45.0  74
2  1  4   7.0   8
```

So this case it must be 6.
I can do it easily with my own code but I have a large data set, so I want to know the  best way to do it .
Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.DataFrame([[4,2,None,7],[1,2,45,74],[1,4,7,8]],columns=(['a','b','c','d']))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does

```
a.loc[a.a == 1].b.sum()
```

work?